# SFSpeechRecognizer - detect voice language out of two

Tags: ios, swift, speech-to-text

I'm developing a voice app for ios, with the ability to use two languages simultaneously. I'm planning to use the SFSpeechRecognizer, however, it requires a language locale to be preset. It can't detect automatically which one is used.

So how can I detect which language is spoken?

Can I use two instance of SFSpeechRecognizer simultaneously, and rely on confidence parameter in the response object?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Have you found a solution? @Ilia Kandrashou