# SFSpeechRecognizer - detect voice language automatically from two languages

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, speech-to-text, sfspeechrecognizer

I'm developing a translator app for ios. it requires a language locale to be present. It can't detect automatically which one is used.

So how to detect the language and how to change locale of SFSeechRecognizer accordingly?

I had referred the below links but there are no answers on this post.

[SFSpeechRecognizer - detect voice language out of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591164/sfspeechrecognizer-detect-voice-language-out-of-two)

[SFSpeechRecognizer multiple languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56270710/sfspeechrecognizer-multiple-languages)

Does any one have idea how to do that in swift.

Comment: I don't think there will be a quick solution for this you would have to create your own ML Model. Apple just started doing this with their translate app I doubt it will be available for the public for a long time.

Comment: It would be great if you know the ML Model reference or share some related link.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml